# Shiny app crashes on Studio/Shiny server while plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny-server, rstudio-server

I am trying to set up shiny server and RStudio server to run on EC2 (AWS, Ubuntu16). This worked very well until I wanted to deploy my own shiny app. I developed this app locally and it also runs perfectly on shinyapps.io!

It loads normally in shiny servers and I can access it, press some buttons, move some sliders but if I upload a file the shiny app starts calculating and I see some values changing but when it comes to the plotting just disconnects.

I then tried it with RStudio Server to see if it works there but it didn't. It works normally until it hast to plot something (I use ggplot2). For example there are features in the app to combine several .csv files and it does this as usual!

Now the part which totally confused me: I then tried to run my regular R script (from which I derived the app, so it does the same but as a script) and this worked totally fine! Afterwards I tried to run the app again it it worked too! It even does when I clean the environment (including hidden files)! But it doesn't if I restart the R session.

I tried to narrow down parts of my regular R script which are needed for the shiny app running afterwards. It seems like if I plot one plot in the script and show() it the Shiny app works afterwards too! So I guessed it might be a graphical problem?

In the app I put together the graph in a reactive({}) and render the plot afterwards:

`output$mappingplot <- renderPlot({
    plot <- well_plots()
    show(plot)
  })`

I just updated RStudio, Shiny Server and R to the latest Versions.
This is part of the shiny-server.log:

```
^[[32m[2017-07-18 15:58:01.308] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mStarting listener on 127.0.0.1:3838
^[[32m[2017-07-18 15:58:40.420] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mCreated bookmark state directory: /var/lib/shiny-server/bookmarks
^[[32m[2017-07-18 15:58:40.429] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mCreated user bookmark state directory: /var/lib/shiny-server/bookmar$
^[[32m[2017-07-18 16:23:44.179] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mStopping listener on 127.0.0.1:3838
^[[32m[2017-07-18 16:23:44.181] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mShutting down worker processes (with notification)
^[[32m[2017-07-18 16:24:22.459] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mShiny Server v1.5.3.838 (Node.js v6.10.0)
^[[32m[2017-07-18 16:24:22.463] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mUsing pidfile /var/run/shiny-server.pid
^[[32m[2017-07-18 16:24:22.465] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mUsing config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
^[[33m[2017-07-18 16:24:22.518] [WARN] shiny-server - ^[[39mRunning as root unnecessarily is a security risk! You could be runni$
^[[32m[2017-07-18 16:24:22.522] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mStarting listener on 127.0.0.1:3838
```

This is the last error from the shiny app:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:43057

Attaching package: ‘shinydashboard’

The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:

    box

Loading required package: XLConnectJars
XLConnect 0.2-13 by Mirai Solutions GmbH [aut],
  Martin Studer [cre],
  The Apache Software Foundation [ctb, cph] (Apache POI),
  Graph Builder [ctb, cph] (Curvesapi Java library)
http://www.mirai-solutions.com ,
http://miraisolutions.wordpress.com
-su: line 1:  2014 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) R --no-save --slave -f \/opt\/shiny-server\/R\/SockJSAdapter\.R
```

I already searched a lot but didn't find anything about the Segmentation fault connected with my plotting. I have no clue what the error might be!

If needed I can also upload the code of the app but it is quite long (and really messy I guess)

Thank you in advance for any help!!

EDIT:
I created a minimal example and uploaded it to github: https://github.com/vektorious/test_app

If I run the app first in a fresh R session it crashes. If I run the testscript first and then the app it works..

Comment: See this Github issue (especially [the comment here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1810#issuecomment-321199508) -- TLDR version: add `options(java.parameters = "-Xss2560k")` at the top of your app). If this answers the problem, either me or someone else can write up an answer for future users struggling with the same thing. If not, also do let me know!

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved the problem!